# bash script error unexpected token error

Tags: bash, shell

```
if [ $USER=root ]; then     echo "hi" else  echo "bye" fi
```

it is giving me the following error

```
line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
line 5: `fi'
```

Comment: maybe add a semicolon before `else` and `fi`? or just don't force all that poor code into one line. or if it's really just that small snippet consider using `&&` and `||` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code:
`if [ $USER == "root" ]; then echo "hi; else echo "bye"; fi`

Comment: `==` is the same as `=`